# What determinates the options in property list of a .plist file?

Tags: iphone, plist

When I try to add an item to an existing iPhone `Info.plist`, the options in the list is not iPhone-relevant (e.g. "*Application is visible in Classic*" which seems to be some desktop OS stuff).

How can I get back the proper list of choices for iPhone? Thanks!

p.s. I found this when editing the `avTouch` sample project's `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be an exhaustive list of all iPhone-relevant entries, but maybe a good start:
[Recommended Keys for iPhone Applications](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW4) and the Bundle Programming Guide's [section on iPhone plist keys](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW5).

Not sure if you can limit the choice in xcode's plist editor to only include iPhone-related keys.